# How can I see what I bought for someone else via their Amazon wishlist?

Tags: amazon, wish-list

I bought several gifts for family members but they all arrived at the same time and I forgot who got what. How can I see purchased items for a list that isn't my own?

Answer (score 7):

So I also find myself in this conundrum with similar aged nephews. I didn't get Dzejms answer to work either but got this to work:

- From the list, choose **Print List**, under the **... More** option at the top right.
- Then when the list show in the browser it is something like: https://www.amazon.com/hz/wishlist/printview/xyz123?target=_blank&ref_=lv_pv&filter=unpurchased&sort=default
- Change unpurchased to purchased in the URL and viola!

Comment: As of Dec 18, 2021, this works. Hooray!

Comment: As of Dec 14, 2022, this works. Hooray!

Comment: As of Dec 14, 2023, this works. Hooray!

Answer (score 2):

Append ?filter=purchased to the URL. Normal URL query string rules apply. If there is already a ? char in the URL, then you have to use &filter=purchased instead. Christmas is saved!

Edit: Looks like Amazon changed their app. Updated the answer.

Comment: Sadly this no longer appears to work. :-(